# Inncorrect render with Telerik RadEditor control (Image inside)

Tags: telerik, radeditor

[image]

My web page render incorrect for radeditor

I think may be css file but now I find how to solve  for 3 hr.

Anyone Can help me?

Answer (score 1):

The problems is most likely due to some global CSS style which is breaking the appearance of RadEditor. You should inspect the stylesheet of the problematic page and search for classes that applies padding / margin to TABLE, TR, TD, DIV, SPAN, UL and LI elements.

You can also try the solution provided in this article: http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/editor/overriding-global-css-styles-inherited-by-radeditor.aspx

If you provide a live url to the page, we can examine it with Firebug / IE dev toolbar and find the problematic class.

Best regards,
Rumen